# it loops again after if else condition

Tags: laravel-5

i have made a loop to increment the date but then it loops as many times as the if condition becomes true.

```
@foreach($c as $cc)
@for($i = $range_from; $i <= $range_to; $i++)

  <div class="text-center">  
      {{ date('m-d-y', strtotime($i)) }}

        <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          @if( $cc->attendance_date == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($i)) )
          <br><h1>present</h1><br>

          @else
          <br>absent<br>
          @endif
        </div>

  </div>

  @endfor
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Perhaps show an example dataset ($cc) and show what the actual output is, and what you expect it to be.